# Android MVVM: how can I update data in a Repository from another Repository, when same data is part of response from different server endpoints?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I'm trying to move `Android` project to `MVVM`. Two different repositories get same data response, when calling different server endpoints. What is the right way to keep both up-to-date?

There are different server endpoints returning `"UserData": "/get_user_data"` and `"/get_user_statistics"`. I need to update data in `"UserRepository"`, when making request in `"UserStatisticsRepository"` (which returns UserData as well).

Should I inject both Repositories in a ViewModel and then set the `"UserData"` via ViewModel to `"UserRepository"`? It just feels to me not really right way to set data to a Repository from a ViewModel...

Let's say, I have:

```
data class UserData(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("name") val name: String
)
```

and

```
data class UserStatisticData(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("active_users_count") val activeUsersCount: Int,
        @SerializedName("users") val users: List<UserData>
)
```

and

```
class UserStatisticRepository(...) {
    ...
    suspend fun makeUserStatisticDataRequest(){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val networkResponse = myAppAPI?.getUserStatisticData(params)
            try {
                if (networkResponse!!.isSuccessful) {
                    _userStatisticData.value = networkResponse.body()?.userStatisticData
                    // TODO: Should I set UserData (networkResponse.body()?.userData) to UserRepository here??? 
                    // How can I access UserRepository?
                } else {
                    throw UserStatisticDataResponseError(Exception("Response body error..."))
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw UserStatisticDataResponseError(Exception("Network error..."))
            }
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your projwct is set up but If I was in this kind of situation I would :

1. Either have a single state that is mutated by both of the repository,  make it reactive. Both of the repostitory can take that state as argument when being constructed and they can also mutate the state.
2. A reactive database that is mutated by both the calls. i.e. whenever any new UserData entity is fetched, its written to databse. When we need UserData we listen it directly from Reactive Database like "Room"  instead of those API endpoints directly.

When to do what?

I would choose the first option if I did not have to persist the fetched data & I am cool with losing all the data once app is closed where as If I wanted the data from those endpoints to survive App restart the  I would go for the second options.

For the first option the code may look like this :

```
data class UserDataSource(val userDataList : List<UserData>)

class UserDataRepo(val subject :  PublishSubject<UserDataSource>){
 UserdataService.getUserData(userID).subscribe{
   // Do calculations to find the old list of user and edit or update the new user 
   subject.onNext(UserDataSource(newUserList))
 }
}

class UserStatRepo(subject :  PublishSubject<UserDataSource>){
   UserdataService.getUserStat().subscribe{
   // Do calculations to find the old list of user and edit or update the new user 
   subject.onNext(UserDataSource(newUserList))
 }}
```

In Ui subscribe to the userDataSource subject..

```
class UserDataViewModel{
   val userDataSource = PublishSubject.create<userDataSource>()
   val userDataRepository = UserDataRepo (userDataSource)
   val userDataRepository = UserStatRepo (userDataSource)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this idea sounds good to me! Maybe the first option is exactly, what I need. Could you please give an example of this single state that is mutated?

Comment: you can make a RxJava publish subject of the list of UserData inside a class called "Datasource". And whenever you get a response from retrofit you can call datasource.userDataListSubject.onNext(listOf(userData) or List<UserData> depending upon the Retrofit call you are making)

Comment: Check the answer I have tried to provide a skeleton of what could be implementation

Comment: You can accept the answer with green tick and upvote if it was helpful :)